# SQL Server: Same backup copy is verified in the original server (SQL Server 2008 Standard) but not in other server (SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, ...)

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have got a production server with SQL Server 2008 Standard version doing backup copies using maintenance plans. I am doing one full copy on Sundays and one differencial copy the rest of the days of the week.

The problem comes when I take the copies to other servers to restore them. In the original server I verify the bak file is OK, but when I do the same on the other servers, it says:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
>   The media family on device '[path].bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I use this script to verify the database:

```
DECLARE @full_fillename varchar(1024);

SET @full_fillename = N'[path].bak';

RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = @full_fillename
GO

IF @@ERROR = 0
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Backup usable'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Backup not usable'
END
GO
```

I test this on my local machine with SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, SQL Server 2012 Standard, SQL Server 2008 Express, SQL Server 2012 Express. But this only works on the original server where the backup is done.

Other notes about the problem:

To restore the database I need to use MOVE commands. For example I use this script to restore the backup file:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [db_name]
    FROM DISK = '[path].bak'
    WITH 
        FILE = 1,
        MOVE N'[db_name]_cs_as' TO N'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.CLASS\MSSQL\DATA\[db_name]_cs_as.mdf',
        MOVE N'[db_name]_cs_as_log' TO N'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.CLASS\MSSQL\DATA\[db_name]_cs_as_log.ldf'
```

See that my database name is "XXXX" and the files to move are called "XXXX_cs_as" and "XXXX_cs_as_log". This issue is because I rename the database in the past.

**UPDATE**

Rename logic and physical names does not solve the problem.

This is fustrating. The original server is a SQL SERVER 2008 STANDARD SP4, and the backup created by this server cannot be restore in any other SQL SERVER that I tested (SQL SERVER 2008 ENTERPRISE, SQL SERVER 2008 EXPRESS, SQL SERVER 2012, etc).

**UPDATE 1**

Server: Windows Server 2008, SQL SERVER 2008 STANDARD SP4

```
select @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64)   Sep  3 2014 04:11:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Other computer: Windows 8.1, SQL SERVER 2008 STANDARD SP4

```
select @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64)   Sep  3 2014 04:11:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

In other computer I cannot restore the backup, neither execute this script:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = @full_fillename
```

Can Windows 8 be the problem?

**UPDATE 2**

I've downloaded the SQL SERVER 2008 ENTERPRISE EVALUATION, I install this version on the original server and my computer (windows 8).

I create a new database in the original server and import a script with the content of the database with the problem (there are only tables and rows).

I make a backup from the new SQL SERVER 2008 ENTERPRISE. I take the backup (.bak) and put it in my computer with the same version of SQL SERVER.

The backup cannot be restored!

**UPDATE 3**

At this time, the problem must be Windows 8, because I virtualized one WS2008 and the backup was restored without problem.

Comment: How do you copy the backup to other server? via FTP? if yes , is it in Binary mode?

Comment: I using Team Viewer to get a copy. Also I bring the files zipped by rar.

Comment: The thing is that I have created a test database with one table, then I made a backup copy and I can see that this copy is verified in the other server. The issue must be something of the database.

Comment: "The issue must be something of the database." - not necessarily. Your test with a simple small database does not rule out transfer errors that are more likely to affect larger files than smaller ones. To confirm that the file is the same once it has arrived at the other end of the transfer, try running a checksum over the source and destination files (if you don't already have a tool for that there are many available like http://www.bitser.org/checksum-calculator-windows-7-freeware.shtml).

Comment: The checksum is not the problem.

Comment: How is the drive formatted on the server that the backup is working fine vs the server where the backup is not working fine ? Also, are you using some FTP method to transfer backup from the working server to another server ?

Comment: NTFS both. I don't use FTP, anyway, I always compress the bak file.

Comment: Good. Any chance that you can check `Bytes per Sector` using  `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo <drive letter>` on both the servers -- post ther results if you can ? Also, you are sure that there is no corruption of any kind by running a clean DBCC CHECKDB ? Any errors logged into sql server or windows event logs ?

Comment: Your backups are being done through SQL Server or some 3rd party tool?

Comment: @JoseTeixeira SQL Server official tools, not 3rd party.

Comment: Have you tried running the backup to a different drive and/or without compression?  There is no possibility of hardware encryption is there?

Comment: If your SQL versions are the same then the only other culprit is the method used to copy the files - it's a known issue that using FTP can corrupt the backup if not done in binary mode. It could be the compression tool you are using or the copy mechanism used by TeamViewer. Is it possible to get a copy of the backup over the network using xcopy or similar, or even physically copy it to external media and move it that way?

Comment: @Nathan, no, that is not problem, because I compress the bak file with WinRar. Anyway, there another SQL SERVER 2008 in one WS2003 that can load the backup. But here, in my machine with Windows 8.1 it's imposible. Now, i am triying to virtualize a WS2008 in my machine to try to load the backup.

Comment: @KennethFisher, not, I make the backup without compression using SQL Server Managment Studio.